# Azure DevOps connecting to remote Artifactory

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to figure out the appropriate way to connect an Azure DevOps pipeline that executes a Maven build to a remote JFrog Artifactory Maven repository.

I first looked at Feeds and Upstream Sources. I didn't see anything in the documentation that shows how to do this. Indeed it looks as though [you can't actually do it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops).

Then I looked at Service Endpoints. Here, I was able to create a service endpoint that points at my Artifactory host. Great! I added a task of Maven Authenticate, which is the only one I saw that allows me to reference the mavenServiceConnection. But the pipeline still fails when trying to resolve artifacts, because it only looks at Maven Central.

```
# Docker


trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
      inputs:
        mavenServiceConnections: 'eti-libs-snapshots-local'
    - task: Maven@3
      inputs:
        options: '-X'
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        publishJUnitResults: true
        testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
        mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
        mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
        effectivePomSkip: false
        sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
        sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'    
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image
      inputs:
        command: build
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Edited: Found some more relevant information

Comment: Have you installed Jfrog Artifactory extension from marketplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as [Kontekst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6334351/kontekst) pointed out, I needed to add the [Jfrog extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension) for pipelines. I have done that and got it configured.

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)